# Обработчик события на элементе

Tags: jquery

Есть несколько элементов с одним классом `.share`, при клике на на этот элемент дочерний `<div>` с классом `.pluso` должен показываться, но ничего не происходит, вот код:

```
$('.share').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('.pluso'));
    if($(this).find('.pluso').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).find('.pluso').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $(this).find('.pluso').css('display', 'block');
    }
}
```

Comment: извините за код(

Comment: Какие ошибки есть в консоли браузера?

Comment: Во-первых, Дмитрий прав - что показывает консоль? Во-вторых, в принципе все выглядит правильно (последняя скобка не закрыта, но это скорее всего недоофрмлено). Наверняка где-то какая-то мелочь мешается. Лучше будет если Вы сделаете fiddle с вашим HTML и JS. Тогда можно будет точно найти проблему.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает обработчик события](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454483/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, там стоит ссылка на этот вопрос, набравшая уже 4 голоса.

Comment: @Visman, ну, будет (в том числе) мини-тест на [роборевьюеров](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1409/178576).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $('.share').click(function() {
> ```

Попробую угадать.

```
$(document).on('click', '.share', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".share").click(function(){
     $(this).children().find('.pluso').show()
});
```