# Не работает обработчик события

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть несколько элементов с одним классом `.share`, при клике на на этот элемент дочерний `div` с классом `.pluso` должен показываться, но ничего не происходит, вот код:

```
$('.share').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('.pluso'));
    if ($(this).find('.pluso').is($('.share').click(function() {
                console.log($(this).find('.pluso'));
                if ($(this).find('.pluso').is(':visible')) {
                    $(this).find('.pluso').css('display', 'none');
                } else {
                    $(this).find('.pluso').css('display', 'block');
                }
            })
            ':visible')) {
        $(this).find('.pluso').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $(this).find('.pluso').css('display', 'block');
    }
})
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обработчик события на элементе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454472/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: Вместо создания нового вопроса, лучше бы отредактировали свой предыдущий: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454472/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, я думаю, лучше, наоборот, тот вопрос объявить копией этого.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да они оба не очень-то хорошие ;) Хотя, я все-таки считаю, что остаться должен первый по времени публикации.

Answer (score 1):

Для примера html код с вашими div:

```
    <div class="share">Содержимое блока
    <div class="pluso" style="display: none">Содержимое дочернего блока</div>
</div>
```

Подключите Jquery: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

А дальше сам обработчик события при клике на главный div:

```
$(".share").click(function(){
            $(".pluso").show();
        });
```

При нажатии на главный div отобразится дочерний. На самом деле вариантов решения задачи очень много - это лишь один из многих.

Надеюсь я правильно понял поставленный вами вопрос.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454472/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5